# How do i use live() show() hide() functions all together?

Tags: jquery

I want to hide and show(toggle like) some information.Since the info is obtained dynamically then i am forced  to use live().But once i click on the element(to hide or show) that particular element disappears,what ami doing wrong.This is where i got so far
                 hook.txt

```
george lucas  
knows  physiology
```

//javascript
$('#stdmatch').load("/details.txt");
            $('.subjectnames').live('click',function(){
                if ($(".detail").is(':visible')) {
                    $(this).hide('slow', function(){
                        $('.detail').load("/info.txt")
                    });
                }else {$(this).show('slow', function(){
                        $('.detail').load("/info.txt")
                    });
                }

`});`

Comment: Are your selectors scoped correctly?  Is .detail resolving to more elements than you intended and don't want to hide?

Comment: Does removing the callback ameliorate things? It might be that the callback is running into trouble retrieving the data, and causing the element to be empty. (Also, I'm sure you already did this, but to be on the safe side, is the element really gone from the DOM? Can you use Firebug to check whether it might still be lurking around?)

Comment: @jake yes the selectors are scoped correctly ...i want to be able to hide and show .detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently hiding and showing `this` instead of `.detail` as your comment mentions.  When you click on `.subjectnames` it is hiding and showing `.subjectnames` not `.detail`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".subjectnames").live("click", function(){
    $(".detail").toggle().load("/info.txt");
});
```

Comment: i heard that you cant use live() and toggle() function together